# Count click inside iframe javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events

I want to count click set condition and display message for 2 condition.
If first time click it will display message "clicked".
I clicked second time it will display "paused clicked".
I am trying this code. It's detecting click inside iframe but not following condition.

```js
var action = 1;
var monitor = setInterval(function(){
    var elem = document.activeElement;
    if(elem && elem.tagName == 'IFRAME'){
    if ( action == 1 ) {
       message.innerHTML = 'Clicked';
        action = 2;
    } else {
        message.innerHTML = 'paused Clicked';
        action = 1;
    }
        clearInterval(monitor);
    }
}, 100);
```

```css
iframe {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="//example.com"></iframe>
<div id="message"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/16sdrqbq/

Comment: does it give any javascript errors in the inspector console?

Comment: @JoshJackson I added jsfiddle there and it's not displaying any error in console.

Answer (score 2):

You clear the interval at the bottom (`clearInterval(monitor);`), so at no point is this function going to run again. It's setting action correctly to 2, but in order for it to check `action == 1`, it would need to run this function again.

Unfortunately, what you're trying to accomplish is not possible (Detecting multiple clicks inside an iframe) if you don't control what's going inside the iframe. The `activeElement` is actually pretty clever, but since clicking again in the iframe wont cause it to change again, there's no way to sense another click. You would have to attach an event to the inner-frame, which requires same-origin access. See [here](https://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).